# NoClassDefFound:while runnig demo of cwac-wakeful

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I have issue with NoClassDefinitionfound, while running com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.demo from https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful, Its not getting the Launcher activity DemoActivity.
Note , I have integrate library for the same from above link.
Please help me,Thanks.

```
07-09 17:20:30.994: E/AndroidRuntime(3107): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.demo/com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.demo.DemoActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.demo.DemoActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.demo-2.apk]
```

Comment: i havent added jar,its a library and i have already added in build path... :P

Comment: i haven't change a single word from project which is given for sample.

Comment: k you want us to go and explore that for you?

Comment: @K_Anas if u have time go and go and explore that this is his comment.

Comment: Do a project clean (Project > Clean in Eclipse, `ant clean` command-line) and see if that helps.

Comment: clean the project and run,bt still the problem remains same... :(

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what to tell you, as the project works fine for me here.

Comment: @commonsware:i m still not able to run project...i have created another project and copied everything from demo of cwac-wakeful,it shows only toast,then nothing happened moreover the log in AppService also not displaying,please help me in this issue.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what to tell you, as the project works fine for me here.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after updating adb.  My external jars were in a directory called "lib" instead of "libs."